# Linking to BLAS when header file is missing

Tags: c, gcc, blas

I am trying to compile a program in C that uses the BLAS interface for linear algebra. The system has the BLAS libraries in `/usr/lib64/libblas.*` (`.a` and `.so` files) but there is no `cblas.h` in `/usr/include`. I tried copying the header locally and compiling the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cblas.h>
int main() {
    double foo[] = {1.1,1.2,1.3};
    printf("Vector norm: %g\n",cblas_dnrm2 ( 3, foo, 1 ));
}
```

with the options

```
gcc blas_test.c -L/usr/lib64 -lblas -I.
```

but get the error `undefined reference to 'cblas_dnrm2'`

How do I correctly link the provided library?

---

Update: if I try linking to `libcblas.so.3` or `libcblas.so.3.0` in `/usr/lib64/atlas` like so:

`gcc blas_test.c -L/usr/lib64/atlas -lcblas -I.`

I get the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas`. Again, it's finding the header file just fine, but doesn't find the shared library object.

Comment: Try changing `<cblas.h>` into `"cblas.h"` and put it into same folder as blas_test.c  `<>` is for system-path, then you don't need `-I.`

Comment: I get the same error if I do that. The compiler is finding `cblas.h` fine, the problem is it's not linking to the libraries that are there. Am I linking to the right library? Should I be linking to `libcblas.so` instead of `libblas.so`?

Comment: Glad you solved it. Put your last comment in an answer and accept it so that this question gets closed. I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that gcc looks for `.a` and `.so` files but not `.so.3` files. Solved with the following:

```
gcc blas_test.c -L /usr/lib64/atlas -l :libcblas.so.3 -I.
```